# Angular 12 Observable<Object[]> Error when trying to perform a get method

Tags: angular, typescript, http, mean-stack

I have been trying to make some sense of this error I'm getting on Angular 12.

**Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.**

This is my service:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Catalogo } from './../Models/Catalogo';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/'

@Injectable ({
 providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CatalogoService {

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 getAll(): Observable<Catalogo[]> {
   console.log(this.http.get<Catalogo[]>(baseUrl));
   return this.http.get<Catalogo[]>(baseUrl);
 }
```

And this is my component:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CatalogoService } from './../../Services/catalogo.service';
import { Catalogo } from "./../../Models/Catalogo";
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-catalogo',
  templateUrl: './catalogo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./catalogo.component.scss']
})

export class CatalogoComponent implements OnInit {

  catalogo?: Catalogo[];
  currentCatalogo: Catalogo = {};
  currentIndex = -1;
  constructor(private catalogoService: CatalogoService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.retrieveCatalogo();
  }

  retrieveCatalogo(): void {
    this.catalogoService.getAll()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.catalogo = data;
          console.log(data);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }
```

Edit: Here's the HTML part

```
<div class="containter">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Id</th>
        <th scope="col">Modelo</th>
        <th scope="col">Precio</th>
        <th scope="col">Especificacion</th>
        <th scope="col">Imagen</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let catalogo of catalogo; let i = index">
        <th scope="row">{{catalogo.id}}</th>
        <td>{{catalogo.modelo}}</td>
        <td>{{catalogo.precio}}</td>
        <td>{{catalogo.especificacion}}</td>
        <td>{{catalogo.imagen}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I was following a tutorial on how to use serializable with MEAN stack:

> https://www.bezkoder.com/angular-12-node-js-express-mysql/
> https://www.bezkoder.com/angular-12-crud-app/

but when I try load the page I get the error I mentioned.

My questions are:

Why this is happening? (I'm kind of new to angular)

is this how you are supposed to return an array with Observables?
"this.http.get<Catalogo[]>(baseUrl);"

EDIT: This is the output for the method on the service class:

```
Observable
operator: MapOperator {thisArg: undefined, project: ƒ}
source: Observable
operator: FilterOperator
predicate: (event) => event instanceof HttpResponse
thisArg: undefined
[[Prototype]]: Object
call: ƒ call(subscriber, source)
constructor: class FilterOperator
[[Prototype]]: Object
source: Observable
operator: MergeMapOperator {concurrent: 1, project: ƒ}
source: Observable {_isScalar: false, _subscribe: ƒ}
_isScalar: false
[[Prototype]]: Object
_isScalar: false
[[Prototype]]: Object
_isScalar: false
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Edit: the output from the subscribe method

```
Subscriber {closed: false, _parentOrParents: null, _subscriptions: Array(1), syncErrorValue: null, syncErrorThrown: false, …}
closed: true
destination: SafeSubscriber
closed: true
destination: {closed: true, next: ƒ, error: ƒ, complete: ƒ}
isStopped: true
syncErrorThrowable: false
syncErrorThrown: false
syncErrorValue: null
_complete: undefined
_context: null
_error: error => { console.log(error); }
_next: data => {…}
_parentOrParents: null
_parentSubscriber: null
_subscriptions: null
[[Prototype]]: Subscriber
isStopped: true
syncErrorThrowable: true
syncErrorThrown: false
syncErrorValue: null
_parentOrParents: null
_subscriptions: null
[[Prototype]]: Subscription
complete: ƒ complete()
constructor: class Subscriber
error: ƒ error(err)
next: ƒ next(value)
unsubscribe: ƒ unsubscribe()
_complete: ƒ _complete()
_error: ƒ _error(err)
_next: ƒ _next(value)
_unsubscribeAndRecycle: ƒ _unsubscribeAndRecycle()
Symbol(rxSubscriber): ƒ [_internal_symbol_rxSubscriber__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.rxSubscriber]()
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Thank you!

Comment: Would be nice to see the *ngFor part as well

Comment: Will be better if you can attach the HTML (the part using `*ngFor`) and sample JSON data to be received from API.

Comment: Also the console.log is from the service part or from the component. Because for me looks like the http call return

Comment: @Osakr it's from the service.

Comment: Better post the console.log of the subscription, so we can see what kind of object is

Comment: I added it, or at least i think that's the one.

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify the things to make it easier. In order to simplify and increase performance I recommend you using the async pipe. Let me show you.

First in your component.ts you don't need a retrieveCatalogo method, we will store the observable and use it directly in the template with the async pipe.

The component:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CatalogoService } from './../../Services/catalogo.service';
import { Catalogo } from "./../../Models/Catalogo";
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-catalogo',
  templateUrl: './catalogo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./catalogo.component.scss']
})

export class CatalogoComponent implements OnInit {
  
  // We use the $ at the end of the var name as a naming convention for storing observables and subscriptions.
  catalogos$!: Observable<Catalogo[]>;
  currentCatalogo: Catalogo = {};
  currentIndex = -1;
  constructor(private catalogoService: CatalogoService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // We call the service and store the observable
    this.catalogos$ = this.catalogoService.getAll();
  }
```

Now in your component template we need to use the async pipe

```
...
    <tbody *ngIf="catalogos$ | async as catalogos">
      <tr *ngFor="let catalogo of catalogos">
        <th scope="row">{{catalogo.id}}</th>
        <td>{{catalogo.modelo}}</td>
        <td>{{catalogo.precio}}</td>
        <td>{{catalogo.especificacion}}</td>
        <td>{{catalogo.imagen}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
...
```

> The async pipe will unsubscribe automatically
> https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Comment: even this throws the same error

Comment: Then take a look at what the backend is returning, to ensure is the right type of data, because as your service works the backend must return just an array of catalogos. If the server, for example, returns the catalogos inside a "data" property or something, then you must use a map operator to only return that data. Also check the code for errors like  ```*ngFor="catalogo of catalogo"```

Comment: @robertoalvarez did you see the backend data? If you do a raw GET request to the endpoint do you get the data in the expected format?

Comment: @Osark, I just did and it is parsing it incorrectly, I'm fixing that now. Thanks for your inputs, it should work after I fix it. Although when I tried doing the async it didn't recognize the line, I don't know why.

Comment: @robertoalvarez if the async pipe is not recognized then probably you are using it in some module where you don't have the angular CommonModule imported. Glad to hear that you find the problem. Also if you want to parse the data somehow you can use rxjs pipe and map operator so you can change the input stream as you want

Comment: its working now! thank you. I can't upvote your answer. And the async is working too. Also thanks for explaining thoroughly .